# Login fails when recreating database with Code First

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using ASP.NET Entity Framework's Code First to create my database from the model, and the login seems to fail when the database needs to be recreated after the model changes.

In Global.asax, I've got the following:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EntriesContext>());

    // ...
}
```

In my controller, I've got the following:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // This is just to force the database to be created
    var context = new EntriesContext();
    var all = (from e in context.Entries select e).ToList();
}
```

When the database doesn't exist, it is created with no problems.  However, when I make a change to the model, rebuild and refresh, I get the following error:

```
Login failed for user 'sa'.
```

My connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="EntriesContext"
     connectionString="Server=(LOCAL);Database=MyDB;User Id=sa;Password=password"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The login definitely works as I can connect to the server and the database from Management Studio using these credentials.

If I delete the database manually, everything works correctly and the database is recreated as expected with the schema reflecting the changes made to the model.

It seems like either the password or access to the database is being lost.

Is there something else I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Code First has a problem using the password specified in the connection string when connecting to a database that has been recreated.  Changing this to use a trusted connection gets around the problem as the password no longer needs to be stored.

So, instead of this:

```
Server=(LOCAL);Database=MyDB;User Id=sa;Password=password
```

Use the following instead

```
Server=(LOCAL);Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=true
```

You may need to add your account or the one being used by ASP.NET to SQL Server and grant it the 'dbcreator' permission so that it can drop and recreate the database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe using sa may be an issue. Either way I believe it is good practice to create a separate user profile to use in your connection string.

Comment: Didn't make any difference.  Creating a new user in SQL Server with the 'dbcreator' permission (which it needs) yields the same result. Database gets created first time, and any subsequent changes to the schema cause the login failed error to be displayed instead of dropping and recreating the database.